# How to programmatically invalidate or refresh JavaScript and CSS bundles without restarting the web application?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-optimization, bundles

I understand that when using bundles for JavaScript and CSS the web application is caching the bundles and using a caching key for it, something like the following:

```
<script src="/bundles/sampleJs?v=h-HGvCLcx-0T1kG3DBKIVBtGxEhtfpONQl5b_7BQuSo1"></script>
```

How can I programmatically refresh the cached bundles (or just one bundle)?

For example, if I have to upload a new CSS update - I want to update the bundles without having to restart the whole web application...

Comment: That would heavily depend on what web framework you are using; please add a tag (since it is not a matter of JavaScript or CSS, and not the responsibility of Bundler).

Answer (score 0):

### Here are two ways you can address the issue:

**ASP.NET:**

If the html page is generated on the server side in let's say ASP.NET, I would simply define a static  global in Global.asax that would be appended to all resources.

```
<script src="/bundles/sampleJs?cacheBustVersion=" + <%= @cacheBustVersion %> ></script>
```

**RequireJS:**

In Javascript, if you're using RequireJS you can create a variable called urlArgs in your requirejs config section.

```
urlArgs: "cacheBustVersion=v1"
```

This will append "&cacheBustVersion=v1" to each file that's loaded via the require call.

**RequireJS during development:**

```
urlArgs: "cacheBustVersion=" Date.now()
```

This will ensure all files loaded through requireJS are not cached.

[RequireJS Documentation for urlArgs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs)

Comment: Hi. I actually want to take advantage of the cached bundles, only I was looking for a way to somehow cause the built-in bundle mechanism to re-do the bundling and minification of the bundled files when I update a CSS file for example...